# How do I run a method from an import script in a javascript worker?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I am new to Javascript and playing with using workers for the first time.

I am having trouble figuring out how to use methods in scripts i am importing. Currently I use yaml.js ( https://github.com/jeremyfa/yaml.js/ ) with nodejs as per the documentation:

```
YAML = require('yamljs');
// Generate YAML
yamlString = YAML.stringify(nativeObject, 4);
```

which works as I would expect but I can't use require in a worker so i use import scripts:

```
importScripts('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/yamljs/0.3.0/yaml.js')
```

but if I try and then run `yamlString = YAML.stringify(nativeObject, 4);` in the worker I get an error. The error is `'Yaml' is undefined` Can someone please help me figure out and understand how I can use yaml.js (specifically the YAML.stringify method in my worker?

Thanks

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The error is "'Yaml' is undefined". I'll update my question.